# Product names looks different from frondend and backend

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have the product name with html tags so written simple script to updated the product name below code i have used for update.

```
Mage::app();
$product_collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
   $sku = $product->getSku();

   $simple_product = '';
   $simple_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
   if($simple_product != ''){

      $name = $simple_product->getName();
      if($name != strip_tags($name)) {
          $simple_product->setName(strip_tags($name));
          $simple_product->save();
      }      
   }
}
```

after that i did the reindex by shall command and cleared the cache.

Now my product names are clear without html tag in frond end like (product list , product view ,search ) all pages looks good. But when i go to admin panel

> catalog->Manage Products

I have a product name with html tag so i am bit confusing here so please kindly clarify what's going on here. Also let me know wh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have `multi store view /multiple website` at your system.In magento,product can be  set *multiple name* basic of `multiple store views/multiple websites`.

As you have `Mage::app();` that means you *initialized the default store*.So it is *take data from default store.*

In admin at each product,**there have left panel Current scope** from there you can view/edit store wise attribute value

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for the answer, But my application does not have multi store i have only one store "base" store with two language like English, French, As you said i have changed two language but still i am getting product name with html tag in two languages.

But now i found that in frond end i have change into french i am getting product name with html tag. Please could you give me any suggestion to complete this.

If i get french product name and again run the this script is useful to fix the issue please suggest me.